# How to calculate the live mobile data speed on Android Programatically?

Tags: java, android

I searched through many questions, but I can only find out how to get the wifi speed. My issue is that I want to know how to calculate the mobile data speed. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? (also, please refrain from tag-spam. Android fragments and your IDE don't have any specific relation to your root issue)

Comment: I am talking about android programming. So i add all  the android studio related tags. And sorry :(

Comment: Have you tried downloading a file with a size known in advance and calculating the average download speed with that? Or do you need near-realtime speed reports?

Comment: i need real time @Machinarius

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/528131 The AsyncTask code in that answer downloads a file "manually", you can take the time it takes to download fixed size chunks of data to somewhat accurately determine data link speed. Be mindful your own code execution time is included in this calculation, so it does not report accurate values.

Comment: Anyways I am reading the codes of Internet speed lite @Machinarius

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes(int)
to get the data usage and then divide by time to get the speed.
Or try this one:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor

Comment: "Return number of bytes received by the given UID since device boot" Doing this would account for an average speed of data since boot, not a very interesting stat

Comment: try the second link

Comment: That code reads the data usage per app, not the real data link speed.

Comment: Oh @Machinarius  !! But I want real time stat. There are many apps doing this .